# Javascript Array Issue

Tags: javascript, arrays

ok, so when i do array=array2 then change something in array2 it changes array. how do i prevent this?

Comment: Thought I should explain why, but it ain't an answer, so here it goes: objects and arrays are passed by reference, unlike numbers and strings.

Answer (score 2):

Do..

```
b = a.slice()
```

Why? Because assignment would just reference the origin object. `slice` or `concat` would create a new object.

Answer (score 1):

`var b = a.concat();`